# Cookie blocked by Chrome

Tags: express, google-chrome, vue.js, cookies

I am trying to set up a simple register/login form with vuejs in the front and a server with express js using the passport library to setup a local and social media startegy.
But I can't seem to pass cookies to the front end when I login with the local strategy.
Also when I sign in with google I get the cookie on the front end but it is not sent with the next API call but this is a subject for another question.

I was confused by this so I made a simple project just to receive and send cookies and it works. Here is the back end:

```
//headers in app.js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});

// index file
router.get('/cookie', function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie("token", "mytoken");
  res.send("cookie sent");
});

router.get('/info', function (req, res, next) {
  cookies = req.cookies;
  console.log(cookies);
  res.cookie("token", "mytoken");
  res.send("cookie sent");
});
```

And here is my front end methods that call the API:

```
methods: {
    async getCookie() {
      await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/cookie",{withCredentials:true}).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    },
    async sendCookie() {
      await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/info",{withCredentials:true}).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
  }
```

With that I have no problem passing the cookie in the requests and receiving it.

Now on my real project I have this on the back end

```
//Headers just like the other project
 
router.post('/users/login', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (user) {
      res.cookie('token', 'mytoken');
      return res.json({ user: user.toAuthJSON() });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Front end call:

```
// Service file to call the api

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const ApiService = {

  get(resource, slug = "") {
    return axios.get(`${resource}/${slug}`).catch(error => {
      throw new Error(`ApiService ${error}`);
    });
  },
...
}
export default ApiService;

//actual call in authetification module file

[LOGIN](context, credentials) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      ApiService.post("users/login", { email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          context.commit(SET_AUTH, data.user);
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(({ response }) => {
          context.commit(SET_ERROR, response.data.errors);
        });
    });
  },
//
```

The request works but the cookie is blocked by Chrome:
[image: cookie warning]

I don't see what is the difference in my two projects that would trigger this warning on Chrome for the last one.

**EDIT: In my original post axios.defaults.baseURL was not set to my actual value.**

Comment: Are you using `localhost:8080` and `localhost:3000` in both cases? It appears that you are from the code but if that were the case the cookie domains would match and the error message seems to imply they don't.

Comment: You are right. I change a bit my code to be more concise for the question. The value for axios.defaults.baseURL was in a config file using 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost. That was the issue. Apparently localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

After last update of chrome browser I also started to get this error. A solution to solve this go to chrome://flags and disable **SameSite by default cookies** and disable **Enable removing SameSite=None cookies**. This will solve your problem. I think another way to solve this changing your cookie settings(samesite attribute) when you are creating your session.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution thank to [@skirtle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583563/skirtle). I set axios.defaults.baseURL to "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/" but localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not interchangeable and considered two different domains. I switched to axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/api" and it fixed the problem.